# Unity, I can't make a Prefab out of a Tilemap

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

When I try to create a prefab this happens:

[I select the tilemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JseOD.png)

[I create the prefab by dragging it down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGenu.png)

[I open the prefab and nothing works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSuDt.png)

There is no way to edit it through its tile palette editor and it has only a tile.
I see this also when I try to instantiate a tilemap (both from a prefab or an already ingame gameobject)
How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

The TileMap Prefab parent must be an object with a Grid Component attached to it :D

Comment: Some more details would be helpful here.